# page not searching as per the argument passed from a splunk page

Tags: splunk

i am redirecting to a knowledge base page from a splunk view.
i am able to pass the value from splunk to KB and it is populating in the search box, but the issue is,
first time when the page (KB page) is opened, it is populating the value in its search box , but some other default result is displaying, but when once the search button is clicked, from next onwards it is showing the correct search results.

Please help
Thank you

Comment: What is the link to the knowledge base page? Is the KB page a splunk app or an external app?

Comment: it was an internal KB page Bug... Thank you very much SilverNinja